# Update value of PHP variable on click with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I was wondering if it is possible to update the value of a PHP variable on click on an HTML element. I would listen for the click with jQuery's `.click()` and transmit some PHP with jQuery's `.ajax()` or one of the jQuery ajax functions and that request would increase the variable by 10 (+=10) ?

How can I do that?

Increase the variable's value for all users when any user clicks. Kind of like a Google +1 or Facebook like button. Except a user can click more than once. and even clicks don't undo.

Is there a way to do this without a database?

Comment: why are you not using a database?

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha because I haven't used a database thus far in developing this web app. And it would be nice not to use any databases. But it sounds like a database is the best and most secure solution. Can you show me how to do it with a database or a text file?

Comment: if this is a small application, you can do it with files. But on a large scale, databases are recomended

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha Fine, you all convinced me to use a database. Can you show me how to do this with a database?

Comment: here's a secret for making db based apps (don't tell anyone!) : Learn MySQL language ;)

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha haha, good secret!

Answer (score 7):

You will need to store the data somewhere.  You COULD write to a text file.  This is terrible in practice.  The best thing to do here is use a database.

Answer (score 2):

Once the PHP renders the page, it's done, no more changes there. To update the page in real-time, you need to use JavaScript (you can use the success function of your ajax call to do it). However, to make this work for all the users, you need to keep the value of that variable somewhere - a database, or even a textfile. Database is *strongly* recommended. After all, that's what they are meant for.

Your ajax call needs to call a PHP function that will increase that value for you and probably echo something to denote whether it was successful. Upon that returned result, you update the existing page by using the success function, like I mentioned above.

Comment: Ah, okay. Could you please include some sample code on how to do this? I know of these methods and even more so now, but not how to do them. An example of how to do this with file storage would be best if you could do that.

Comment: People at Stack Overflow don't write codes/homework for others. We help by giving solutions and fixing the existing code (though you haven't provide any). There are tons of resources online - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php.html#MySQL, for example...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without a database — you could store the value in memory (memcache, redis) or a flat file.

However, an in-memory store isn't going to persist across crashes or reboots, and a file-based solution could result in hangs or delays, as only one client can have write access to the file at a time.

Why don't you want to use a database? If you don't have MySQL access, you could try sqlite.

Comment: I don't want to use MySQL simply because the web app I am building hasn't needed to use MySQL thus far and it would be nice if it didn't need to at all. It's part of the #NoSQL movement. I know if may sound stupid.

Comment: Well, if you have a NoSQL store (Mongo?), that's a database, too. Store the value there.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily store the data in $_SESSION (http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) or in a cookie (http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php). You cannot store this data permanently without a database.

Comment: Sessions are user specific though.

Answer (score 1):

There are <del>three</del>two ways to do this without database.

## file storage

store the value of variable in a file using `file_put_contents` and retrieve it using `file_get_contents`, increase by ten and save it again in the same file.

## serialize or export

using functions `var_export()` or `serialize()` , you can store variables and arrays in files. Serialization and unserialization is more resource intensive but in terms of storage space, its more effective than exporting.

Example:

```
<?php
include 'data.php';
$data[$_POST['itemid']]  += 10;
$towrite = var_export($data, true); 
file_put_contents('data.php',$towrite);
?>
```

and here is what data.php should look like before executing the above code:

```
<?php
 $data = array( 'myitemid' => 0);
?>
```

just replace `myitemid` with the unique identifier the like button is on.

<del>#sessions#

you can save data in a session, but beaware , this data is short lived.</del>

Comment: session would not be very useful here, as he wants the stored value to be the same for all users, while a session is user specific...

Comment: @PeterVR Yes, I don't see a session working well. As this is supposed to be for all users.

Comment: Can you show me how I could go about doing this with either, file storage, serialize, or export. In other words, could you add a sample implmentation with one of your methods to your answer?

Comment: how do I do that with the jQuery ajax function though?

Comment: How, can you show me how to a POST request with $.post() in jQuery or $.ajax() ?

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

**Option:** You can use input field to store the value temporary, its faster than filesystem manipulation and do not have size limit.

**Another Option:** other option is using innerHTML of a div or another html element, i prefer input field because is easy to serialize and use in another ajax event and than its easy to persists. For example using json is fast and easy to save in MongoDB.

**Example using input:**

javascript example:

```
$('.classname a').click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url : '/foo',
            type: "POST",
            data: $("form.bar").serialize(),
            error: function(){
            },
            success : function(data){
                $('.input_class_name').val(
parseInt($('.input_class_name').val())+parteInt($('.another_input_class_name').val())
);
            }
        });
    });
```

html example( with 2 forms, using like this you can submit in diferent moments or put in the same form):

```
<form class="foo1">
<input type="hidden" class="another_input_class_name" value="10" />
</form>

<form class="bar">
<input type="hidden" class="input_class_name" value="10" />
</form>
```

Comment: If I can store it in an input field, then can't I store it in the innerHTML of any element? If so, can you update your answer so that it is stored in the innerHTML of a div.

Comment: Yes, i'll update the answer. The advantage of input field is easy to serialize and use in another ajax event